# page not found in spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I've imported the maven `spring boot project` into eclipse.

When I was running the first time, Ideally this page should run in browser `http://localhost:8080/showCreate`. But its showing `page not found error`.

I thought tomcat is missing, So I've installed it and tomcat was running fine. I was able to see `http://localhost:8080` running for tomcat. And after that, I started my spring boot project, but its showing 8080 port is already occupied.

So I stopped tomcat server and then restarted `spring boot project`, now it ran successfully. But `http://localhost:8080/showCreate` is not running and showing `page not found` error.

This project I've imported from udemy developed in `spring IDE tool`.

How to configure `web application` with `Tomcat` and run from eclipse ?

May I know please what I am doing wrong?

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=maria@123

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

server.servlet.context-path=/locationweb
```

createLocation.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Create Location</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="saveLoc" method="post">
<pre>
Id: <input type="text" name="id"/>
Code: <input type="text" name="code"/>
Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
Type: Urban <input type="radio" name="type" value="URBAN"/>
    Rural <input type="radio" name="type" value="RURAL"/>
<input type="submit" value="save"/>
</pre>
</form>
${msg}

<a href="displayLocations">View All</a>

</body>
</html>
```

LocationController.java

```
@Controller
public class LocationController {

    @Autowired
    LocationService service;

    @Autowired
    LocationRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    EmailUtil emailUtil;

    @Autowired
    ReportUtil reportUtil;

    @Autowired
    ServletContext sc;

    @RequestMapping("/showCreate")
    public String showCreate() {
        return "createLocation";
    }

}
```

Comment: add code including properties file and controller

Comment: @Hemant Code added

Comment: remove property `server.servlet.context-path=/locationweb` and try running project from your IDE.

Comment: Wow It worked. May I know please why it worked without this property ?

Comment: Spring boot applications are accessed by context path “/” which is default for embedded servers i.e. we can access the application directly at `http://localhost:PORT/`

But in production, we will deploy the application under some context root – so that we can refer the URLs for other places. Also, it is desirable to configure security and there we will need application’s context root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your context path :

For version spring-boot 2.xxx use:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/locationweb
```

For Spring-boot version 1.xx version use :

```
spring.server.context-path=/locationweb
```

and then access it as : 
`http://localhost:8080/locationweb/showCreate`

If you will remove this property from properties file then there will not be any context and you can access you page at : `http://localhost:8080/showCreate`

Comment: What's a use of this property ?

Comment: this property sets context-path for you application.